# on_notify does not get triggered

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token

I am using a very simple example:

**mycontract.hpp:**

```
[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]] 
void depos(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo);
```

**mycontract.cpp:**

```
[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]] 
void depos(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo) {
  check(false, "notification handler triggered successfully");
}
```

By calling `eosio.token::transfer`, the transaction happens successfully, but my function `depos` does not get called.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the contract containing the `on_notify` attribute should be either the sender or reciever of the transfer. This is not clearly mentioned in the manual

Answer (score 1):

Notification is delivered by `require_recipient`. `eosio.token::transfer` calls `require_recipient` for `from` (sender of token) and `to` (recipient of token) account. As @towi_parallelism mentioned, only sender and recipient can get notification.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/d7bc0a5c/contracts/eosio.token/src/eosio.token.cpp#L89-L90

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **EOSIO_DISPATCH** with **ACTION** keyword,
then replace **ACTION** keyword with **[[eosio::action]] void** from your .hpp file and remove **EOSIO_DISPATCH** from your .cpp file of smart contract.

As **EOSIO_DISPATCH** blocks **eosio::on_notify**.

Also check: **[[eosio::on_notify("VALID_EOSIO_ACCOUNT_NAME::VALID_EOSIO_ACTION_NAME")]]** Ref: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/v1.6/guides/generator-attributes

Please closely check eosio.token contract you will get how use.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/tree/master/contracts/eosio.token